# Ktlint ignores .editorconfig

Tags: kotlin, editorconfig, ktlint

I wanted to try out Kotlin and ktlint and I was happy to see that it supports tab indentation via the editorconfig file (since [this PR](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/pull/841/files)). Sadly it doesn't seem to work for me. I haven't used editorconfig before, I might have made some simple mistake.

My `.editorconfig` in the root folder:

```
indent_style = tab
```

My gradle file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val koinVersion: String by project
val junitVersion: String by project

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.30"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.0.0"
}

group = "me.me"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

application {
    mainClassName = "de.me.bot.translate.MainKt"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.sksamuel.hoplite:hoplite-core:+")
    implementation("org.koin:koin-core:$koinVersion")

    testImplementation("org.koin:koin-test:$koinVersion")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion")

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "13"
}
```

However running gradle ktlintCheck still throws exceptions because of unexpected tab characters. I don't understand why. I ran it with --debug, but it didn't give me any useful information.

[Here is my project: github.com](https://github.com/findusl/translate_bot_kotlin/tree/8b70a1220e49410e431686b6ea67bf22fc193b46)

Comment: I think your project is hidden

Comment: @YuriSchimke How stupid of me, thanks. It's visible now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EditorConfig specification [states](https://editorconfig-specification.readthedocs.io/):

> With the exception of the root key, all pairs MUST be located under a section to take effect.

So your .editorconfig file should be:

```
root = true

[*.{kt,kts}]
indent_style = tab
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I had never worked with editorconfig before and Intellij seemed to just accept it like that. I was searching the mistake in ktlint the whole time.